# Autocompleted fields by the browser not updating Angular bound variables

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, analytics

I'm experiencing a problem in an Angular 7 application. Clients coming to the web site with Microsoft Edge on Windows 10 seems to have the autocomplete (or autofill) of web forms enabled.

The problem is that each field of the application has :

- Analytics event to track user's behaviour
- Auto save feature, sending a request to save the value (on change)

When using autofill, those events are not triggered. No matter if we use ractive forms or template-driven forms, the bound property is not updated as the change comes from outside the Angular zone. Moreover, when the field is filled by the browser, not only are we missing data causing all sorts of errors, but the front end validations passes. The form is then valid and the user is able to trigger a function with incomplete data.

I tried the ChangeDetectorRef, no luck.

To reproduce, you can change the value of a field programmatically using pure JS outside of Angular zone (say, at the end of the index.html)

```js
// somewhere at the end of index.html
setTimeout(() => {
  let field = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
  field.value = 'Hello World!';
  
  field = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[1];
  field.value = 'Hello World!';
}, 2500);
// ----- end of index.html snippet


// app.component.ts
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'js-angular';

  test = 'Hi';
  fg: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.fg = this.fb.group({
      test: ['Hi']
    })
  }

  doIt() {
    console.log(this.fg.get('test').value);
    console.log(this.test);
  }
}
// ----- end of app.component.ts snippet
```

```html
<form (submit)="doIt()">
  <input type="text" name="test" [(ngModel)]="test">
  <button type="submit">Envoyer</button>
</form>

<form (submit)="doIt()" [formGroup]="fg">
    <input type="text" formControlName="test">
    <button type="submit">Envoyer</button>
</form>
```

My question is : Is there a clean way to have autofilled fields update the Angular bound variables and trigger the analytics events?

The solution I have for now is to get the values from the fields using `document.getElementById('idOfThePotentiallyAutofilledField')`

Note that this solution is temporary to reduce the number of production errors.